# Convergence radius of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty 4^{-k}kz^k$

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

How can one find out the convergence radius of

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 4^{-k}kz^k$$

Can I do

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{4} {\frac{1}{4^k}} = \infty$$?

Comment: what do you think? by the way, what exactly are you doing taking this limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

If  $a_k=4^{-k}kz^k=k\left(\dfrac z4\right)^k,$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n+1}n\cdot\dfrac z4=?$$

Now if $\dfrac z4=1,a_k=?$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_k=\frac{k}{4^k}.$ Then

$$ | \frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}|= 4 \frac{k}{k+1} \to 4$$

as $k \to \infty.$

This shows that the radius of convergence is $=4.$